# Is STDIN_FILENO a default input for /bin/more?

Tags: c, pipe

I have written a very simple pipe in a small C code where the parent process writes to the pipe and the child process reads it and displays through more. I have used `dup2` to attach the read descriptor to `STDIN`.

```
    else /* where pid=fork() is 0 */
    {
            close(fd[1]);
            if(fd[0]!=STDIN_FILENO)
            {
                    if (dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO)!=STDIN_FILENO)
                    {
                            perror("dup2 redirection");
                            exit(1);
                    }
            }
            close(fd[0]);
            execl("/bin/more","more",(char *)0);
    }
```

The last part has been taken from some existing code. My question is how does `/bin/more` knows that it has to work on `STDIN`. If I run simple more on AIX session, it throws error. But when more runs with `execl`, from a C code, it runs without any argument and it considers `STDIN` as argument. Can some one please explain?
I have written simple pipe before as well. I need to read specifically using the read descriptor. But here it seems that `/bin/more` does it without being instructed to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `more` reads from standard input if it is not given a file to read.  If the input is a pipe (or file) and the standard output is a terminal, it will read from standard output (which sound preposterous, but actually works).  But if the input is a pipe and the standard output is not a terminal, it is designed to then behave like `cat`, because normally it will read from the terminal at the end of each page of output, but that's where the data is coming from anyway.

To get it to work 'normally', you'd have use a "pty" (pseudo-tty) for the input, which is not a trivial exercise.

Comment: @Jasen: Thanks; auto-spell correct on a tablet is a pain when writing on SO.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. But what confuses me is this o/p - $>more
Can't take input from a terminal
usage: more [-Ncdeilsuvz] [-t tag] [-x tabs] [-p command] [-n number]
            [-W option] [file ...]

Comment: I think probably I got my answer. I changed my code by removing dup2. I get the same error which I get when running more without sending any arguement. Now my C code matches AIX session. Thanks for your help Jonathan.

Comment: I've not seen that usage message before.  Different systems have different implementations, though.